# Determine whether the mappings are topologically conjugate

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, group-theory, solution-verification

**Let, H be the set of all homeomorphism from $\mathbb{R}$ onto itself. Let, $f_1$, $f_2$ $\in$ H such that $f_1(x)=2x$ and $f_2(x)=3x$ under the group composition. Prove that, $f_1$ and $f_2$ are conjugates.**

**Thought:** I come up with a map which is either injective or surjective. But couldn't find the bijection. Otherwise, it turns out to be complex , contrary to the condition.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take, $g(x)=x^{\frac{\ln 3}{\ln 2}}$ when $x\ge 0$ and $g(x)=- (-x)^{\frac{\ln 3}{\ln 2}},x<0$ this will give you a conjugation between $f_1,f_2.$

Actually, to find a map which will give a conjugation, we need to solve the functional equation,  $f(2x)=3f(x)$ and we are interested in the solution which is a homeomorphism from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}.$ Now, by checking we see that $g$ of course is a solution of the functional equation.

Comment: Can you please describe how did you come up with this map ?